# How to share Company's directory with all users using Google Apps shared Directory?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-script

I am using the code given in the answer to this question:

[Is it possible to pull my Company directory into Google sites intranet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33711/is-it-possible-to-pull-my-company-directory-into-google-sites-intranet)

However, as it specifies, it works for admin only. Would it be possible to make the directory available for other users of Google Apps as well? If yes, how could that be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the Shared Contacts API? This would put these additional contacts into your users' Google Contacts (accessible via Gmail). If you would prefer not to work with APIs, there are 3rd-party products in the Google Apps Marketplace that do this - https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/search?query=shared+contacts

Answer (score 0):

In that specific answer, I gave two possibilities to obtain a list of users:

1. Via a script (but you need to have admin privileges)
2. Via a Google Spreadsheet

If you go by the second method, then that particular sheet can be shared throughout the domain by the admin. Another route is to place the sheet on your website (Google Sites).

The trigger on the script, will make sure that the sheet is refreshed regularly.